# How to prove $\{a^nb^na^n \mid n\geq1\}$ is not regular using pumping Lemma

Tags: automata, regular-languages

Here the problem is that I’m confused how to take the pumping value $p$ is it arbitrary any value?

Also I don’t know if I should prove all $3$ conditions of the pumping lemma is false or if any one should be proved as false by considering the given language as regular by proof by contradiction.

Comment: Usually this community stays away from answering homework questions, so people want a poster to say something like, "I did these steps but then at the next step ..."  But I'll give you an outline.  Assume for contradiction the language is regular.  Let the pumping length be *p*.  Consider the string *s=a^pb^pc^p*.  It decomposes into *s=xyz* where by the PL's first clause the *xy* substring is all *a*'s and by the second the *y* substring is nonempty.  Now consider the strings generated in the third clause.  Show that one of them is not in the language.  That can't be.

Comment: Ok I should prove only 3rd clause or all 3 clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's recall the Pumping Lemma statement:

> *For all regular language $ L $, exists a positive constant called $ p $ (i.e. $ p \geq 1 $) such that every string $ w $ in $ L $ with length $ |w| \geq p $ exist strings $ x, y, z $ such that $ w = xyz $ and that statisfying the following conditions:*
>
> - $ |y| \geq 1 $
> - $ |xy| \leq p $
> - $ xy^iz \in L, \: \forall i \geq 0 $

So yes, $ p $ is an arbitrary value and a fixed costant, called "pumping length". The proof for your language may be the following:

Let's assume that $ L $ is a regular language, so for all strings $ w \in L $ it must satisfy conditions of PL.
Now choose a string $ w $ that is in $ L $, let choose $ w = a^pb^pa^p $ and we can split $ w $ in $ xyz $, so let's say that:

- $ x = a^k $
- $ y = a^h $
- $ z = a^{p-h-k}b^pa^p $

with $ h \geq 1 $ and $ h + k \leq p $.

Now note that the first two conditions of the PL are satisfied, but for the third, if we take $ i = 0 $ then $ w = xy^0z = a^ka^{p-h-k}b^pa^p = a^{p-h}b^pa^p $ and this string clearly doesn't belongs to $ L $ and this contraddict the initial assumption of $ L $ regular, so this meanings that $ L $ isn't a regular language because it doesn't satisfy the PL.

Comment: note that you need to check *all* possible $xyz$ subdivisions of $w$.

Comment: @ratchetfreak no, the statement of the PL says that all regular languages $ L $ bla bla bla, for **all** $ w \in L $ those conditions are valid, so if I show that exists $ w \in L $ that does not satisfy those conditions this implies that $ L $ it isn't regular.

Comment: The $w$ is quantified with a *for all* $(\forall)$, while the factorization $xyz$ is quantified with a *there exist* $(\exists)$. In the negation, as you said, $w$ gets a *there is* $(\exists)$, but also the factorization gets a *for all* $(\forall)$. They are referring above to the latter.

Comment: I don't get it, I show that exists a string $ w $ that contraddict the assumption based on the _for all $ w \in L $_ of the PL, so it's proved that $ L $ isn't regular.
Also I didn't understand  your second comment, I choose the $ xyz $ util to me for show that exists a $ w $ that contraddict the assumption.

Comment: I am only saying that their comment is a valid feature that a proof should have. On the other hand, your argument does cover all possible valid factorizations $xyz$ for the $w$ exhibited.

Comment: So what do you would add to the proof? Sorry but I still don't understand what are you saying, give me an example or something else.

Comment: I am not saying anything about the proof. I am only saying that the comment above "note that you need to check *all* possible $xyz$ subdivisions of $w$" is correct, even though your argument is doing so. I am made the remark because you replied "no" no it.

Comment: Oh ok, there was just a misunderstanding from the first comment, sorry